# How to avoid thread in threadpool dead when exception thrown without try catch

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, threadpool

My code looks like this:

```
public class ExceptionTest {
    public static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionTest.class);
    public final static ThreadFactory factory = new ThreadFactory() {
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable target) {
            final Thread thread = new Thread(target);
            log.debug("Creating new worker thread");
            thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                    log.error("Uncaught Exception", e);
                }
            });
            return thread;
        }

    };
    final static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    int i = 1;
                    int j = 0;
                    System.out.println(i / j);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The console only print the message one time. This means the thread has died. Is there any other way to prevent thread death (except `try catch` block, this is much repeated code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not achieve this without using `try...catch` block, see [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3):

> If no catch clause that can handle an exception can be found, then the
>   current thread (the thread that encountered the exception) is
>   terminated.

---

And, I do not think the termination of threads in a cached thread pool is a problem, since next time you submit a new task, a new thread will be created to handle it.

---

If it really matters, and you do not want repeated code, you can write a wrapper class like this:

```
public class WrapperRunnable implements Runnable {

    Runnable runnable;

    public WrapperRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                runnable.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And submit `WrapperRunnable` to executor:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        int i = 1;
        int j = 0;
        System.out.println(i / j);
    }
};
WrapperRunnable wrapperRunnable = new WrapperRunnable(runnable);
executor.execute(wrapperRunnable);
```